# Update multi-line graph D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to update a d3 multi-line graph by pulling data at 5 second intervals from a mySQL database using PHP. At the moment the graph is displaying but not updating - I know that there is something not right with my updateData function but have tried everything can think of and nothing seems to work.  Can anyone please help?

https://gist.github.com/Majella/ab32fe0151fd487da3f6

**UPDATE**:

As you can see the x-axis line is only showing sporadically and some of the lines aren't lined up with the y-axis.

Updated gist:

https://gist.github.com/Majella/ab32fe0151fd487da3f6

[image]
**UPDATE 2**:  For some bizarre reason the lines are changing colour - or moving completely not exactly sure.  So while on graph above the lines are from top - blue, orange then white - when graph updating the blue might move to bottom with orange on top and white in middle etc - but happening randomly?

Comment: I suspect that your data needs to be bound based on an id. That is, to make sure the data properly binds to the same DOM elements each time. Perhaps check https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data

Comment: Thank you - changed key to parameterID instead of parameterType and did the trick:)

Comment: I've been battling this exact same problem for a long time. Your question and solution worked great for me...thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original drawing of the graph, you correctly use:

```
var parameter = svg.selectAll(".parameter")
.data(data, function(d) { return d.key; })
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "parameter");
```

which joins the data (data) to the elements (g.parameter)

During your update function, you will need to join the data again in order to perform updates, deletes, and adds of elements. The [3 little circles tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html) is an excellent place to learn more about this.

Anyway, in your update function, you may want something like this (untested):

```
// re-acquire joined data
var containers = svg.selectAll("g.parameter")
    .data( data );

// update existing elements for this data
containers
    .select( "path.line" ) 
    .attr( "d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - still few problems - see UPDATE above?